# Calculate RTT in Ethernet segment 100 Mbit

Tags: networking, network-protocols

I need to calculate Round Trip Time in an Ethernet segment 100 Mbit. The calculation is made via UDP protocol with Record TimeStamp option, the block of data in UDP is 64byte. 
Also I need to draw the structure of data transported in the channel.

Answer (score 1):

to calculate RTT it would be proper to use tcp syn sent segment compared with syn received .
calculating boths timestamps would give you req o/p.. IN order to structure udp streams us wireshark's FOLLW UDP STREAM OPTIN.. AND convert it into ascii or raw format....